# "none" appearing in classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

***I am trying to learn classes and I don't understand why my code is printing "none"?***

**CODE**

```
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def introduce(self):
    print("Hello my name is " + self.name +" and I am "+ str(self.age) +" years old.")
  
  def crazy_talk(self):
    print(self.name +" says I'm a test")


p1 = Person("John", 36)
p2 = Person("Bob", 23)
p3 = Person("Joe", 3)
p4 = Person("John", 17)
p5 = Person("Ronald", 102)
p6 = Person("Kevin", 55)
p7 = Person("Albert", 70)

people_list=[p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7]

for human in people_list:<br>
  print human.introduce()
```

---

**OUTPUT**

Hello my name is John and I am 36 years old.
None
Hello my name is Bob and I am 23 years old.
None
Hello my name is Joe and I am 3 years old.
None
Hello my name is John and I am 17 years old.
None
Hello my name is Ronald and I am 102 years old.
None
Hello my name is Kevin and I am 55 years old.
None
Hello my name is Albert and I am 70 years old.
None

Comment: As an aside, you **really** should be using Python 3, Python 2 is beyond it's end of life, and is no longer supported

Answer (score 1):

This happens because on your last line you are printing out the return value of calling the `human.introduce()` method. This is always `None`. The `introduce` method itself prints out the the introduction text, but then returns no return value.

To fix, change your last line to just `human.introduce()`. Or alternatively, change your `introduce()` method to *return* (but not print) the text, and then print the result of calling the `introduce()` method on your last line.

Answer (score 1):

So, that expression `human.introduce()`, it doesn't return anything.

```py
def introduce(self):
    print("Hello my name is " + self.name +" and I am "+ str(self.age) +" years old.")
```

This method definition says that, when called, that string will be printed out, but it does not actually return any value to the caller of the method, hence `None`.

So here, where you call the method

```py
for human in people_list:
     print human.introduce()
```

For every human you call the method which will print out the string, and then the method will implicitly return `None` to the caller. This `None` is what the `print` inside of the for loop receives.

If you want the call to `human.introduce()` to return a string that can be printed, then you can change it to this

```py
def introduce(self):
    return "Hello my name is " + self.name +" and I am "+ str(self.age) +" years old."
```

Which will not perform the side effect of printing the string, but it will return the string to the caller.

(Also for your own good, please transition to learning python 3 if at all possible. Python 2.7 is more than a decade old and is no longer supported)